# MySQL Date stored as 12h without AM/PM

Tags: php, mysql

I just realized, 6 months after a system went live, that an insert query had an `h` instead of an `H`, so that a bunch of entry dates were stored as 12 hour dates without an AM/PM indicator. Is there a relatively simple method of fixing this problem? The database is powered by `MySQL 5.1.56-log`.

I'm an idiot.

Comment: No, there's no way to know what the actual times were.

Comment: Well, it is 1 of 2 times.  So....   Start coin flipping.

Comment: If you stored the data without storing a very relevant piece of information... well then... obviously no.

Comment: I'm attempting to write a Python script to process a MySQL export. Essentially compare each date time with the last one, and if it's less, add 12 hours. Seems like it'd work?

Comment: Can you match these inserts with apache access logs or something? If these inserts were from something like `POST /blog/entry` then you can try to relate the access log timestamp to the mysql one. Long shot and tedious, but something to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write a Python script that achieved what I needed, so if anyone else ever runs into this problem, this will work to fix it. (Hooray!)

```
import datetime
#example data
entries = [
    ('2014-10-10 04:07:48', 1, 1136, 'JH'),
    ('2015-04-13 08:31:33', 0, 3066, 'Mez'),
    ('2015-04-13 09:38:06', 0, 3067, 'VL'),
    ('2015-04-13 10:34:54', 1, 3068, 'J.A'),
    ('2015-04-14 02:43:08', 1, 3069, 'ACM'),
    ('2015-04-14 03:35:49', 0, 3070, 'ACM'),
    ('2015-04-14 08:30:39', 0, 3071, 'Ic'),
    ('2015-04-14 09:35:07', 1, 3072, 'DK'),
    ('2015-04-14 10:38:36', 0, 3073, 'ZG'),
    ('2015-04-14 11:36:09', 0, 3074, 'VL'),
    ('2015-04-14 12:46:23', 1, 3075, 'EB'),
    ('2015-04-14 01:44:18', 0, 3076, 'EB')]

last_date = datetime.datetime.now()
last_time = last_date.time()
after_noon = False
twelve_hours = datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
for entry in entries:
    current_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(entry[0], '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
    if current_date.date() != last_date:
        last_date = current_date.date()
        after_noon = False
        last_time = current_date.time()
    else:
        if after_noon:
            current_date = current_date + twelve_hours
        else:
            if current_date.time() < last_time:
                after_noon = True
                current_date = current_date + twelve_hours
    print "('" + str(current_date) + "', " + str(entry[1]) + ", " + str(entry[2]) + ", " + "'" + entry[3] + "'),"
```

This is specific to the columns in my MySQL export, but can easy be adapted to other schemas.

Comment: This obviously is a solution extremely specific to your situation, where you have specific rules you can lean on to make decisions. This is unlikely to be generally applicable.

Comment: I think that given a similar situation (storing dates as 12 hour by mistake), this code is easily adaptable to other data sets.